# Reactjs conditional render not showing even when conditional variable is accurately set

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I am attempting to render a spinner after an onClick event, so the loading icon will show while another function is running (in this case, my glitcher() function). My render function is below. The onClick calls a handler which sequences setting of state, also shown below.

Right now, onClick calls handleGlitch, and the state glitchLoading is properly set true (tested with the console.log call within the conditional) but the spinner doesn't render.

onClick handler handleGlitch():

```
  handleGlitch() {
    this.setState({ glitchLoading: true }, () => {
      this.glitcher()
    }); 
  }
```

Render Function:

```
render() {
    let previewImage = null;
    let loader = null; 
    if (this.state.originalFiles.length !== 0) {
      previewImage = <img className="folder-icon" src={placeholder} alt="" />;
    }
    if(this.state.glitchLoading) {
      console.log("loading"); 
      loader = <Spinner color="primary" />; 
    }

    return (
      <Container className="previewComponent">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <legend>
              <b>Upload Images:</b>
            </legend>
            <input
              className="fileInput"
              id="myfileinput"
              type="file"
              onChange={this.handleShow}
              multiple
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col className="uploadField">
            <Container className="imgPreview">{previewImage}</Container>
          </Col>
          <Col className="optionField">
            <OptionsForm
              value={this.state.distortion}
              valueChange={value => {
                this.setState({ distortion: value });
              }}
            />
            <Button
              color="danger"
              onClick={this.handleGlitch}
              className="glitch-button"
            >
              Glitch Images
            </Button>
            {loader}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Put a minimalistic example in a sandbox like https://codesandbox.io/s/new, the problem that your component no rerendering after `glitchLoading` set to `true`?

Comment: So, the problem must be in the Spinner somehow. Your component's simplified version is working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/91qzqx841r As @DennisVash asked if you can put a minimalistic sandbox, people can easily dig it.

Comment: What does `this.glitcher()` do?

Comment: @devserkan I am struggling to get the same behavior in a sandbox, but will try and like one soon.

Comment: @jered this.glitcher() manipulates an array of images and then calls a callback sending the manipulated image data back up. I don't think it should matter?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try binding this to your onClick function. 
onClick={this.handleGlitch.bind(this)}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, all my functions are bound prior. The onClick is executing properly, and the code after the setState in the handler executes as well. The issue seems to be in the actual re-rendering...

Comment: I figured it was worth a shot, that was the only thing I could see that stuck out in the code that was posted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, quite by accident. For some reason, wrapping the call to this.glitcher() in setTimeout with a 1-millisecond delay worked. See below:

```
handleGlitch() {
    this.setState({ glitchLoading: true }, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.glitcher()
      }, 1); 
    }); 
  }
```

Comment: So the problem is in `this.glitcher`